# How to delete a pipeline trigger in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

How do you delete a pipeline trigger in Azure Synapse Analytics with the UI?

**What's the problem?**

I currently can't publish my workspace changes. I get the following error:

```
TestTrigger1
Trigger 'TestTrigger1' cannot be activated and contain no pipelines
```

This is correct. I disconnected `TestTrigger1` to try a different trigger. However now I can't publish and I can't delete the trigger in the UI either.

In Data Factory, there is a UI option in the bottom left of the pipelines screen to delete. See this [blog post](https://thebernardlim.com/adf-remove-triggers/).

However in ASA, there is no UI option for managing triggers and I can't find one.

[image]

How do I delete this trigger so I can republish?

Comment: Please use the [tag:azure-pipelines] tag **only** for questions related to Azure DevOps pipelines, not other types of pipelines in other Azure offerings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Synapse, you can see all the triggers under the **Integration** section under the **Manage** tab. If you have right permissions you should be able to see the delete button wHen you hover your mouse overt the trigger you want to delete.

[image: Delete triggers in Azure Synapse]

Comment: Excellent thank you. I think I'd spent too long in data factory and was getting some UI blindness!